# Should the browser download multiple images when using srcset?

Tags: html

my html markup is as follows:

```
<img srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/xxx/image/upload/c_scale,w_300/v1653408278/notforsquares/ll/DSCF4429.jpg 300w, https://res.cloudinary.com/makingthings/image/upload/c_scale,w_600/v1653408278/notforsquares/ll/DSCF4429.jpg 600w" sizes="(min-width:300px) 50vw 100vw" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/makingthings/image/upload/v1653408278/notforsquares/ll/DSCF4429.jpg" alt="Lamp" />
```

When I look at the network tab in the inspector it shows two images downloaded. Is that the correct behaviour?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct behaviour. By using `srcset` you're basically setting all the possible image sources the browser can use (and their sizes). You should also use `sizes` attribute to indicate which image (and it's size) the browser should use on different breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

###### Yes, if you open it on a wide-screen device, it will load only one image like the example below:

[image]

###### Otherwise, if you open it in small-screen device, it will load only both image like the example below:

[image]

this is the code he use to implement the elva-fairy image:

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
                     elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w" sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,
                    800px" src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

Link to the web: https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/responsive-images/responsive.html

You can use the `picture` tag if you want to load it only once based on screen size:

```
<picture>
          <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
          <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
          <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
</picture>
```